# Find out number of active locks on a table

Tags: sql-server, locking

I was wondering if there is a way to find out the number of active locks held on a table in SQL Server?

Comment: Have you looked at DMVs like [`sys.dm_tran_locks`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190345.aspx)? Where have you looked?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is a start. Remember that locks can go parallel so you may see the same object being locked on multiple `resource_lock_partition` values.

```
USE yourdatabase;
GO

SELECT * FROM sys.dm_tran_locks
  WHERE resource_database_id = DB_ID()
  AND resource_associated_entity_id = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.yourtablename');
```

Please look at the documentation for [`sys.dm_tran_locks`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190345.aspx)

Comment: I I just noticed that the above answer gives the number of locks on the table but does not give locks on pages and entities on that table. Is there a way to get those locks as well?